# What is KeyError: 'string' in import?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

Does anyone can explain why it is happening? I have module that includes sale, now when i import product an error pops up saying:

```
  File "/opt/openerp/custom_server70_addons/extra-addons/base_import/models.py", line 220, in parse_preview
     fields = self.get_fields(cr, uid, record.res_model, context=context)
  File "/opt/openerp/custom_server70_addons/extra-addons/base_import/models.py", line 117, in get_fields
     cr, uid, field['relation'], context=context, depth=depth-1)  
  File "/opt/openerp/custom_server70_addons/extra-addons/base_impor/models.py", line 104, in get_fields
    'string': field['string'],
KeyError: 'string'
```

I tried to change

```
'string': field['string'];
```

which is found on the default module, into

```
'string': field.get('string')
```

and it works fine, but i don't want to change the default code because it might cause trouble in future.

**Any help is much appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

It seems one of your field does not have string.

Ex:

```
'my_field': fields.char(string='my string')
```

Check your all the fields and add string label in your field and try to import the records again.

Comment: Do i need to put string='my string' for all fields.type? i.e fields.char, fields.many2one, fields.boolean,fields.function etc.

Comment: I already put string='Field Label' but still it output key error string.

Comment: Go to `/opt/openerp/custom_server70_addons/extra-addons/base_impor/models.py: 104` and print the value of field variable `print field` and check the error is raised for which field.